# Can't use MEGA as Transmitter and UNO as Receiver nRF24L01

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, communication, spi, nrf24l01+

I have a project with 7 May Deadline, i really need help on this. Here is the problem, I need to use my Arduino MEGA 2560 as transmitter and Ardino UNO(CH340G) as receiver. I can use uno as transmitter and mega as receiver , but vice versa doesn't works.
I've used the tutorial on this site :
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-wireless-communication-nrf24l01-tutorial/

All codes, connections are same, but when i set MEGA as transmitter and uno as receiver, there is no data coming to Serial port of Uno. I really need help on this, i will be very very very grateful. Thank you so much.

Code on MEGA(transmitter)

```
/*
* Arduino Wireless Communication Tutorial
*     Example 1 - Transmitter Code
*                
* by Dejan Nedelkovski, www.HowToMechatronics.com
* 
* Library: TMRh20/RF24, https://github.com/tmrh20/RF24/
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}
void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  delay(1000);
}
```

Code for receiver(UNO)

```
/*
* Arduino Wireless Communication Tutorial
*       Example 1 - Receiver Code
*                
* by Dejan Nedelkovski, www.HowToMechatronics.com
* 
* Library: TMRh20/RF24, https://github.com/tmrh20/RF24/
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}
void loop() {
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}

    PINS ON MEGA : 
    3.3 -- VCC  
    GND -- GND  
    8   -- CSN  
    7   -- CE  
    51  -- MOSI  
    52  -- SCK  
    50  -- MISO  
    PINS ON UNO :
    3.3 -- VCC  
    GND -- GND  
    8   -- CSN  
    7   -- CE  
    11  -- MOSI  
    12  -- MISO  
    13  -- SCK
```

Comment: Please show your actual wiring for both devices. Also your code would help.

Comment: I have edited my post, thank you so much i will be very grateful for all helps please.

Comment: Are both your modules identical? If you swap the modules over does it start working?

Comment: I will try it now thanks for advice :D i hope it works

Comment: It didn't worked , but thanks for help :D Still waiting for somone to help me btw :D i ll be very thankful if someone can , thanks a lot.

Comment: Shame. Still, we know it's not the modules at fault.

Comment: Did you add a capacitor to the 3V3? https://www.instructables.com/id/NRF24L01-Fixing-Connection-Issues/

Comment: I didn't i 'll try when i get home but vice versa works, mega can work as receiver but not as transmitter, but thank you i will try , still waiting for help , thanks